# CSS Wrap content in div

Tags: html, css

I want to wrap the content inside .container in another div, and give the new div class="content". As you can see, I've already started but I can't figure out how you're supposed to do it. I couldn't really find any help online regarding this so I could be doing it completely wrong.

```
.container { 
        div class="content" {;
        width: 60%;
        min-width: 640px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #FFFFFF;
        padding: 8px;
        }
        </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div class="content" {` isn't valid CSS for specifying styles. Use this syntax instead:

```
.container div.content {
     width: 60%;
     min-width: 640px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     background: #FFFFFF;
     padding: 8px;
}
```

### Explanation

`SELECTOR1 SELECTOR2 { RULES }` is CSS syntax that means "Any element matching SELECTOR2 found as a child (or grandchild, etc) of any element matching SELECTOR1, give it RULES"

`.CLASS` is CSS syntax for a **selector** that means "Any element where the `class` property contains CLASS."

One specifies multiple classes by separating them with whitespace, e.g. `<div class="foo bar">` would be hit by selector `.foo` as well as `.bar`, but *not* by `.foobar`.

`ELEMENT.CLASS` is CSS syntax for a selector that means "Any `<ELEMENT>` element where the `class` property contains `CLASS`."

So putting this all together, `.container div.content { padding: 8px; }` means "Any `<div>` element where class contains `content`, nested anywhere under any element where class contains `container`, give it padding=8px."